# Error: Failed to lookup view "landing.ejs" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
var express = require("express"); var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/",function(req,res){

res.render("landing");
});

app.listen("2121",function(req,res){ console.log("yelpcamp server is running!!!") });
```

Comment: show us your folder structure and also add `app.use(express.static('view'));`

Answer (score 0):

you may add this line of code:
`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`
after:
`app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`

Note: Here 'views' is a folder name that contain ejs files.